# How to add toolbar in Aloha editor 2

Tags: javascript, aloha-editor

I am using aloha editor 2 in my project. Everything works fine but I am not seeing how to add/show toolbars so that I can bold or add a table in my page. I see there documentation and learned this things can be done programmatically but in aloha editor 1 there was an option to add a toolbar.

Was wondaring, if aloha editor removed the toolbar option or I can show toolbar in aloha editor 2 like aloha editor 1.

Answer (score 0):

Searching the docs I can't find a way to add a whole toolbar, but they did add ways to add buttons and bind functions such as bold, underline, etc. to the buttons.

You can find it here: [Aloha Editor: Add & Bind a Button](http://www.alohaeditor.org/docs/#add-and-bind-a-button)

So you can still add a toolbar just not in **1 line of code**.

I personally like it because I get to make a custom ui that would fit my current project's theme.